# Is it sensible to use a ramdisk on a build server?

Tags: build, build-process, continuous-integration

At my company we are currently researching various strategies for speeding up our CI builds. We have profiled our builds and determined that we are constrained by an I/O bottleneck. We have quite a few options to deal with that in the near future (~1-2 months) but would really like to see an improvement *now*.

I proposed using a ramdisk as the checkout and buildfile location. The build outputs and logs would of course be stored on physical disk.

Is that a sensible thing to do or are there significant drawbacks to this approach? I am not looking for answers that regard the hardware side of things but rather than if the interaction between common build systems (e.g. MSBuild) and a ramdisk will cause any issues and if there are other risks I need to be aware of.

Comment: A simple note: I assume you are talking about nightly builds here? in which case of course you need to squeeze the maximum of builds from scratch and tests.. If it were daily builds, I suggest to keep the build time around a maximum of 5 Mn so that developers can get a quick feedback on potential problems at each commit: in this case, it is most of the time useful to do *incremental* compilation, i.e., just do an svn (hg/git/etc.) update, and use Make (or Ant, Nant, etc) to re-compile what has changed. With a good written Makefile, it might also speed-up things dramatically. Just my 0.02€ :-)

Comment: I am talking about CI here (build after every commit). We already take advantage of incremental builds for that but thank you.

Comment: @Christophe Muller, making a blanket statement that a build should be `maximum of 5 Mn` is really ridiculous without knowing the environment, size, and requirements of the build.  We have a product that runs on a CI server and builds in less than two minutes including compile and packaging.  We have another product that includes several .NET solutions, several native windows services, multiple Adobe Flex projects, unit testing, code coverage, packaging, and automated deploy to a test rack.  The entire process (not all of which is run with every check-in) is over two and a half *hours*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as you have enough memory, it's a very sensible thing to do.

The only real drawback is, naturally, your build gets lost on shutdown/power failure which usually isn't a big concern for the CI builds.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran some tests on my "build server" (actually a Powershell script) which checks out 3600 files from Subversion, compiles them (DOT.NET) and runs some Unit Tests.

On my normal (not super fast) hard drive the process takes 35 sec.

Using the Dataram RamDisk tool with the default FAT32 setup on Windows 7 is takes 45 sec.

Reformatting it with NTFS brings that down to 30 sec.

But using an SSD (in my case a OCZ Vertex 2) only takes 27 sec.

I did several test runs but the times are always the same.

What can we learn from this?

A Ram disk is not always faster, make sure you test different products with different 
settings.

A Solid State Drive may even be faster than a RAM disk, which surprised me.

Comment: I have a DataRam ram disk and an ssd and the ran disk is significantly faster.  Something seems fishy if you're seeing the ramdisk take more time than the ssd.  Besides that, this build is already pretty fast and most of the time is probably not I/O bound.  35 seconds is really fast for a checkout/build.  Our build is much larger--was edging up over an hour with unit tests before we optimized and got it down to ten minutes.

Comment: Interesting, I did expect the RamDisk to be much faster than an HD or SSD, so I was disappointed by my results. I'm still in the process of adding more projects and tests to my build process and will re-run my tests again later. If you have already enough RAM a RAM-disk is also cheaper and doesn't wear out the SSD. Thanks for your input Samuel.

Comment: That does not sound right. Short of cache nothing is faster than RAM; not even an SSD. Did you by any chance make your RAM disk so large that there was not enough memory left for the build process to actually do its job? That might have led to swapping memory out to the filesystem which would obviously have an inverse effect.

Comment: I agree with @McKrassy - it sounds like too much RAM was allocated for disk. There's no way an SSD is faster than RAM, just look at the specs for the interfaces.